# Rule for going from roots/asymptotes to intervals of a rational inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, roots, rational-functions

Suppose I have a rational inequality, like

$$
\frac{(x-4)(x+4)}{(x-1)^2} < 0
$$

I can manually check between the roots (4,4) and asymptote (1) by plugging in value like 3 to see that:

$$ 
−4<x<1 \text{ and } 1<x<4
$$
Or in interval terms:

$$
(−4,1) \text{ and } (1,4)
$$

Now, is there an algorithm to simply look at the roots/aymptotes, in this case (4,4,1), and know without plugging anything in what the interval or inequality of x is?

I know it's trivial in this case but imagine you had more massive polynomials causing lots of sign switching.  Is there a technique for getting the inequalities/intervals from just looking at the roots/asymptotes of the rational function?

Note: I've been following along here https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/SolveRationalInequalities.aspx Basically want to see if there's a way I can do these rational inequalities faster, and deal with bigger ones quickly.

Comment: The function $$
\frac{(x-4)(x+4)}{(x-1)^2} < 0
$$
may only change its sign at its zeroes or where it's not defined.

Comment: Multiply throughout by a square so that you're dealing with a polynomial, then recognize that sign changes happens only when the degree is odd. The [wavy curve method](https://brilliant.org/wiki/wavy-curve-method/) is one way to visualize it, but you should be able to do it directly after some practice.

Comment: Robbie: Fixed (had inequality reversed on initial post). Hoppe: Thanks, is there a word for "roots" + undefined points which I can update my question with?  Calvin: Thank you! Reading now.  Could you elaborate this into an answer?

Comment: @CalvinLin does the wavy curve method work on regular polynomials the same as rational functions?

Comment: Essentially yes. But for simplicity, convert it to a regular polynomial by multiplying throughout by a square.

Comment: @CalvinLin I might suggest noting on your amazing site (https://brilliant.org/wiki/wavy-curve-method/) that it works in cases other than the f(x)/g(x) but with less steps [maybe link to a simpler explainer for the polynomial case]?  The way I read it I thought maybe this was particular to rational functions only.

Comment: Then again I suppose f(x)/1 works for f(x)/g(x) so maybe it's obvious to others. Also noticed that on that URL, they don't seem to mention your simplifying method of multiplying to get a polynomial.